# TCP Server in python sending files to TCP Client with Spring integration

Tags: java, python, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I need to implement a TCP Client with Spring Integration, using annotation, without xml conf.

The TCP Server has to send files, and i have to use Spring Integration to handle them, and print them (for now). So, i make a TCP Server with python, but there is no importance for this. Code :

```
import socket as s

host = ''
port = 2303

co = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)
co.bind((host, port))
co.listen(5)
print("Server is listening on port {}".format(port))

conn, addr = co.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)

while True:
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        if not data: break

        print("Client Says: " + data)
        conn.sendall("Server Says:hi")

    except s.error:
        print("Error Occured.")
        break

print("Closing connection")
conn.close()
```

And for the client here is the code using spring integration :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.transformer.ObjectToStringTransformer;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;


@Configuration
public class TCPInputChannel {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TCPInputChannel.class);

    @Bean
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
        LOGGER.info("create TcpNetClientConnectionFactory");
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 2303);
        cf.setSingleUse(false);
        cf.setSoTimeout(10000);
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    TcpInboundGateway gateway() {
        LOGGER.info("create TcpInboundGateway");
        TcpInboundGateway g = new TcpInboundGateway();
        g.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
        g.setClientMode(true);
        g.setRetryInterval(1000);
        g.setRequestChannel(input());
        return g;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel input() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "respString")
    ObjectToStringTransformer stringTransformer() {
        LOGGER.info("create ObjectToStringTransformer");
        ObjectToStringTransformer st = new ObjectToStringTransformer();
        return st;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "respString")
    public String receive(String recv) {
        LOGGER.info("Recv: " + recv);
        return "echo";
    }

}
```

When I run it, the server can make a connection, but he can't send messages, and the client don't print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AbstractConnectionFactory` uses:

```
/**
 * Reads data in an InputStream to a byte[]; data must be terminated by \r\n
 * (not included in resulting byte[]).
 * Writes a byte[] to an OutputStream and adds \r\n.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class ByteArrayCrLfSerializer extends AbstractPooledBufferByteArraySerializer {
```

By default. So, your server should ensure `\r\n` in the end of package it sends.

Or you can select any appropriate deserializer for your purpose: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories

Comment: I setted my code to ensure CRLF line separator, but he write that the connection with the host is aborted. And my client Don't receive any messages, he just have exceptions when i switch offf the server.

Comment: You also should ensure that server receives messages delimited by the `\r\n` as well. That is how client works by default.

Comment: And if I want to configure the end of each package, what is the best way ? Use one of the other deserializer ?

Comment: That's true. You can select any provided (de)serializer, but both sides must agree the contract.

Comment: Okay, how to make a custom one with spring ?

Comment: Just implement `Serializer<byte[]>, Deserializer<byte[]>` and inject into the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory`. See `org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer` package for the help and ideas.

Comment: I'm interested with the `ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer` one, because my messages are in XML, and they're always prefixed with same tags. So, can we used any characters with this one ? Because I can't use it and I don't see how to make a custom one.

Comment: As you see no, it doesn't allow to configure prefix/suffix. You may consider to use `ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer` or just copy/paste `ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer` logic to your own class with your particular terminators.

Comment: You mean to put all `ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer` class, or juste the `doDeserialize()` method ? Because I can't set inputStream myself isn't it ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean or what you miss. Just open `ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer` source code and copy and paste its content to your own class with your own prefix and suffix. Deserves separate SO question. Not sure how to help you else...

Comment: Yes, sorry, i will open a new question to improve my explication.